# Laravel 4: Controller Method Not Found

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm brand new to Laravel 4 and just trying to get started. I can't seem to get the routes and controllers to work nicely together.

I am trying to navigate to:

```
http://localhost/laravel/public/vehicles
```

Using the controller **VehiclesController.php**

```
<?php

class VehiclesController extends BaseController {

public $restful = true;

public function getIndex() {
    return View::make('vehicles.index');
}
}
```

and the route

```
Route::controller('/', 'VehiclesController');
```

I have a view created in `views\vehicles\index.php` which only contains HTML.

Here is my routes table:

```
+--------+-------------------------------------------------------+------+----------------------------------+----------------+---------------+
| Domain | URI                                                   | Name | Action                           | Before Filters | After Filters |
+--------+-------------------------------------------------------+------+----------------------------------+----------------+---------------+
|        | GET|HEAD /                                            |      | VehiclesController@getIndex      |                |               |
|        | GET|HEAD index/{one?}/{two?}/{three?}/{four?}/{five?} |      | VehiclesController@getIndex      |                |               |
|        | GET|HEAD|POST|PUT|PATCH|DELETE {_missing}             |      | VehiclesController@missingMethod |                |               |
+--------+-------------------------------------------------------+------+----------------------------------+----------------+---------------+
```

I have looked at other posts and still can't quite figure out where I am going wrong. Thanks!

Comment: What server are you using, and did you configure pretty URLs properly?

Comment: Try `http://localhost/laravel/public/vehicles/index`

Comment: @ceejayoz I am using WAMP. I didn't mess with any of the settings.

Comment: @user3158900 No luck -- same problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to hit

```
http://localhost/laravel/public/vehicles
```

then

```
Route::controller('/vehicles', 'VehiclesController');
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. The OP had the root `/` as the route.